# Time Manager date format without time

Tags: qgis, timemanager

I want to use Time Manager plugin with QGIS 2.18.9 and unable to correctly format the date and assign it to a field within a table.

I have an imported table with a field called "Year Built" containing a year value as a long integer (looks like "2015"). I want to use that value in Time Manager. Time Manager needs Gregorian format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.ssssss.

I have tried a number of ways to convert it in the expression dialog and place it in a new field called TM_Date. While in the Expression Dialog the "Output Preview" shows . But after clicking on OK and UPDATE ALL, the result in the field is a NULL value.

My last attempt was the following:

```
to_datetime( format_date(concat(to_string( "Year Built") ||'-01-01 01:01:01.001'),'yyyy.MM.dd HH.mm.ss.zzz'))
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: As you already have clear answer by underdark, this is just abut how to avoid `NULL`. On the `Field calculator` there is `Output field type` pull-down menu. You need to select *Date* then your expression should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`YYYY-MM-DD` is supported, so this should be sufficient:

```
"Year Built"||'-01-01'
```

Comment: 'to_date( concat(to_string( "Year Built")||'-01-01'))'